# c# How to create an array of label

Tags: c#

How to create an array of label??

Comment: Erm, without more detail, you won't get much better than Andrey's answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why closing? The question is perfectly legal. 'Not a real question' != 'stupid question'

Answer (score 6):

```
Label[] labels = new Label[N];
```

then fill the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
   labels[i] = new Label(...) { ... };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Label[] label = new Label[10];
```